# mi consola queda en negro con allegro 4 codigo basico

Tags: c++, c, allegro

Tengo el siguiente problema necesito ayuda con urgencia y es que al intentar hacer mi primer proyecto en allegro 4.algo mi comsola se congela y solo se ve la pantalla en negro el codigo es el siguiente

```
#include <allegro.h>
#include "inicia.h"

#define maxfil 11
#define maxcolm 11

BITMAP *bufer; BITMAP *oceano;

char mapa[maxfil][maxcolm]={
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    "O--------O",
                    "O--------O",
                    "O--------O",
                    "O--------O",
                    "O--------O",
                    "O--------O",
                    "O--------O",
                    "O--------O",
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    }; void dibujarOceano() {
    for(int fila=0;fila<maxfil;fila++){
        for(int columna=0;columna<maxcolm;columna++){
                if(mapa[fila][columna]=="O"){
                draw_sprite(bufer,oceano,columna*30,fila*30);
            }
        }
    }



} void pantalla(){
    blit(bufer,screen,0,0,0,0,330,330); } int main () {
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();

    set_color_depth(32);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 330, 330, 0, 0);

    bufer=create_bitmap(330,330);
    oceano=load_bitmap("roca.bmp",NULL);
    while(!key[KEY_ESC]){
    dibujarOceano();
    pantalla();
    }
    system("PAUSE");;
    return 0; } END_OF_MAIN ()
```

tambien lo hice sin el while y sucedia lo mismo 
Agradesco a cualquiera que me pueda ayudar es una emergencia

Comment: Compila siempre con warnings. gcc con `-Wall` te dice donde está el error.

Answer (score 0):

Has pedido a Allegro que se ejecute en una profundidad de color de 32 bits. Esto puede fallar, incluso pedir 24 bits en un sistema de 32 bits puede fallar. Podes intentar usar desktop_color_depth ()

Fijate que set_gfx_mode () no devuelva un error antes de continuar, y que todos los mapas de bits estén realmente cargados. (not == null)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda no sabes lo que me alegra que alguien este intentando ayudarme. todavía sigo con el problema no habrá alguna otra cosa que conozcas